# Drush drupal download - problem with permissions

Tags: drupal, command-line, drupal-7, drush

I am trying to download Drupal using drush. I want to download it on my local apache server /Library/WebServer/Documents/localsite. I am running on OS X El Capitan.

I set all directiries to 755 permission only / (root folder - macintosh hd) not.

when I run:

```
drush dl drupal-7.x
```

I get this error:
Directory / exists, but is not writable. Please check directory permissions.                                        [error]
Project drupal (7.x-dev) could not be downloaded to //drupal-7.x-dev.

Comment: download it in other folder and move files with mv command line into your wanted folder

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to download the site files into your root directory `Directory / exists, but is not writable. Please check directory permissions.`, that `/` usually means root directory.

Try `cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/localsite` then `drush dl drupal-7.x`.

Also, I'm not clear what this means "I set all directiries to 755 permission only / (root folder - macintosh hd) not." But I don't think setting all file permissions from root on down is a great idea.

Comment: Smartest and fastest solution was to download it somewhere else and then move it. I wanted to save some time....

Thx anyways!